# Get only the track (audio) of SoundCloud, not the entire widget

Tags: wordpress, soundcloud

i want to share, in a WordPress website, the songs i upload in SoundCloud.
Because i'm working on a player, i need only the song itself, not the widget.
It is possible?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If the files are yours (i.e. you can also put them on your own server) I would omit Soundcloud, put the files on your own webspace and play them with your own player.

Comment: Did you check the soundcloud API? https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading

Comment: I have just seen the Soundcloud Api and 'Register a new app' is 'Currently unavailable', so i think the answer for my question is no

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible.
I have watched the SoundCloud Developers page and the option 'Register new app' it's currently unavailable for a long time.